# "are graduated" or "graduated"?

Tags: active-vs-passive

I've read some essays in order to improve my english but I am confused about the below sentence.

"In the future, having job experience will put you at a huge advantage against your rivals who apply to the same position. For example, both candidates **are** graduated from the same college, have similar grades and an acceptable resume."

If we use "are graduated", i think this will be passive, is it right?
Should we use like that?
Or, Can we use both "with are" and "without are"?

Thanks.

Comment: Google Books has precisely ***one*** written instance of [***are** graduated from the same college*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22are+graduated+from+the+same+college%22), compared to [dozens of instances](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22graduated+from+the+same+college%22+-%22are+graduated+from+the+same+college%22) of the same without ***are***. If you insist on including an auxiliary (I don't recommend it), note that [***have** graduated from the same college*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22have+graduated+from+the+same+college%22) is far more common.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this is just incorrect.  Everyone reading this will wonder what the hell the author is doing.  Perhaps the author is an English-leaner as well.  The only time one would ever say "are graduated" is in a very scientific sense, and it has a different meaning that does not involve schools.  For example, there is a liquid measuring tool, which is basically a measuring cup, which is referred to in science professions as a "graduated cylinder".  In this case, the word "graduated" has something to do with the fact that something is happening in steps, relating to the word "gradually".  It has nothing to do with the article you are referring to  and has nothing to do with graduating from college or graduating from a class.  Unless you plan to read academic journals in English, such as the summaries of research on PubMed, or unless you plan to get a job as a chemistry teacher in English or a labratory researcher, you will likely never encounter this type of use of the word "graduated", which is the only use where "are graduated" is possible (without being wrong).

Answer (score -1):

It is better (and sounds better) to use "graduated" without "are".

Comment: Kindly avoid answering without any proof of the content..

Comment: I'm commenting as a reviewer because your question was flagged as low quality because of its length. As you can see, this puts it at risk for being voted down, or even deleted. It's important to justify an opinion like this so that learners can learn from your answer about how to make their own decisions. I would suggest adding more explanation and citing a reference, if possible.